# Does Kafka console consumer use auto.offset.reset?

Tags: apache-kafka

My consumer.properties is updated with auto.offset.reset=earliest.

I create a simple topic.

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic some-topic --create
```

I start a producer

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic some-topic
```

Produce some messages.

```
> msg1
> msg2
> msg3
```

Now start a console consumer.

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic some-topic
```

***My expectation:***

It should consume those 3 messages.

***actual:***

It is not showing those 3 messages. If I try to produce msg4, then it is consumed.

Why?

Note: I do understand that I can use `--from-beginning`.
But the question is here why the property is not working?

Comment: you can check if the consumer group of your application where the commited offset is, if it is at the last offset of the topic, then maybe you set the properties the second time the machine started

Comment: I added the log. You can check. there is no commited offset. Every time we start consume consumer, it creates new group.

Comment: could you also post your entire consumer.properties file please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start console consumer after the producer, the default setting `auto.offset.reset` is `latest` so it will wait for new messages to arrive.

I also don't see you pass the file to your console consumer command, you have to pass `--consumer.config consumer.properties` option to your command then only the consumer will use your config

To prove this in code, if you don't provide this file through cmd params the consumer will not load it: check here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L308

```
val consumerProps = if (options.has(consumerConfigOpt))
      Utils.loadProps(options.valueOf(consumerConfigOpt))
    else
      new Properties()
```

See this: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#id1

Comment: I also pointed out to the source code if you are interested to read @RamPrakash

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use kafka-console-consumer, it'll be a different group.
So, when there is a consumer with auto.offset.reset=earliest alreadying running, if you start another consumer with --group to be the same as the last one "console-consumer-10212", then new one will start from the beginning.

Comment: "when there is a consumer with auto.offset.reset=earliest alreadying running" -- the question is - why it is not consuming from the beginning!

Comment: @RamPrakash because you forgot `--from-beginning`? `consumer.properties` is not a "default property file"

Comment: I did not forget. This is the answer "consumer.properties is not a "default property file"",. I assumed it was.